# Remove whitespace with strip method in python in scrapy script, ways to avoid the none in extract

Tags: python, scrapy

the strip method return none if is empty and i would like to know the better way to do it

```
import scrapy

class GamesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "games"
    start_urls = [
        'myurl',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('ol#products-list li.item'):
            yield {
                'name': game.css('h2.product-name a::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'age': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(1)::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'players': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'duration': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'dimensions': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first().strip()
            }
```

Comment: It might be easier if you pasted in the traceback. It's pretty obvious that `extract_first()` isn't returning a string, but you don't include its source.

Comment: you can look at the type of an object by doing `print(type(object_name))`, have you done that? it should tell you if it's a string or not

Comment: Post your error message and the error lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document of Scrapy (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) said:

> using .extract_first() avoids an IndexError and returns None when it
>   doesn’t find any element matching the selection.

So some extracts return `None`, not is a `string`, so it raised error object no attribute `strip()`. You should handle it when `None` value is returned.

Comment: when i remove strip it returns result and generates a valid json, how can avoid in that sentence the none?

Comment: Can you share your valid json on your question? I think you should share detail with error and response you received?

Comment: i did this:   'dimensions': game.css('.list-price ul li:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first(default='').strip(), but i think that could be a better way to do it..

Comment: we have multiple solutions to handle it and this is one. You should update your trick on your quetion :))

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way for handling data like this is using an [item loader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with an appropriate processor.
It has the added benefit of making your parsing code look less cluttered.

The code to do so might look like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, Compose


class GameLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = Compose(TakeFirst(), str.strip)


class GamesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # spider setup skipped
    def parse(self, response):
        for game in response.css('ol#products-list li.item'):
            loader = GameLoader(item={}, selector=game)
            loader.add_css('name', 'h2.product-name a::text')
            loader.add_css('age', '.list-price ul li:nth-child(1)::text')
            loader.add_css('players', '.list-price ul li:nth-child(2)::text')
            loader.add_css('duration', '.list-price ul li:nth-child(3)::text')
            loader.add_css('dimensions', '.list-price ul li:nth-child(4)::text')
            yield loader.load_item()
```